# 'VoiceState' object has no attribute 'disconnect' (discord.py)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

**Problem**

Hello, I am learning `discord.py`. During my coding I tried to create a bot that can Join and Leave a voice channel in my discord server. When I try to run the code it has an issue. The bot join the channel perfectly but when I type `()leave` in the discord chat I got this error in the console.

**Error**

> 'VoiceState' object has no attribute 'disconnect'

This is the the code of my bot.

**Code**

```
@client.command(pass_context = True) # Join Voice Channel.
async def join(ctx):
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    print(f"Joining into: {channel}.")
    await channel.connect()

@client.command(pass_context = True) # Leave Voice Channel.
async def leave(ctx):
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice
    print(f"Leaving: {channel}.")
    await channel.disconnect()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling `disconnect` on the `VoiceState`, which, as your error shows, you can't because it doesn't have a function with that name. A quick look in the [API docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=disconnect#voice) suggests you should call `disconnect` on the `VoiceClient` instance, not the `VoiceState`.

You can get the `VoiceClient` out of the `ctx`.

```
@client.command() # Leave Voice Channel
async def leave(ctx):
    channel = ctx.voice_client.channel
    print(f"Leaving: {channel}.")
    await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()
```

PS. Starting from Discord Rewrite, Discord now automatically passes `Context`, so the `pass_context=True` kwarg is completely obsolete.

Comment: Thanks you a lot, it worked. Now I can use ()join and ()leave very well. Thank you!

Comment: @Giuseppe if it worked then you should mark my answer as correct